# How to set initial queue length in Simpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

I am just starting to work on an event simulation, and I am having some issues with the queue length. The question is how can I set an initial queue in the following code? For instance, is there a way to set the initial_queue = 200 so that when the simulation begins there are already 200 cars in the queue?

```
import simpy

num_of_machines = 1

env = simpy.Environment()
bcs = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=num_of_machines)


def process_client(env):
    with bcs.request() as req:
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            yield req
            print('Car %s starting to charge at %s' % (i, env.now))
            yield env.timeout(90)
            print('Car %s ending charge at %s' % (i, env.now))
            print('Queue size: %s' % len(bcs.queue))
        env.process(process_client(env))

env.process(process_client(env))

env.run(until=300)
```

Which returns:

```
Car 1 starting to charge at 0
Car 1 ending charge at 90
Queue size: 0
Car 2 starting to charge at 90
Car 2 ending charge at 180
Queue size: 0
Car 3 starting to charge at 180
Car 3 ending charge at 270
Queue size: 0
Car 4 starting to charge at 270
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are on the right track, but your while loop never ends so the `env.process(process_client(env))` never gets executed, but would be a unwanted recursive call anyway.

I broke your code into two parts.  The first part models just one car trying to get a charge.  The second creates 200 of instances of the first process.  Note that we are creating these processes before the model starts.  The model does not start until we the `env.run(900)` line executes.  When the model starts, all 200 processes will try to grab the resource and 199 of them will get queue.

here is the code

```
"""
Simple example of starting a resource with a queue of 200 requests

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

def charge_process(env, res_pool, car_id):
    """
    Models a car waiting in a queue for a charger 
    and charging
    """
    with res_pool.request() as req:
        yield req
        print('Car %s starting to charge at %s' % (car_id, env.now))
        yield env.timeout(90)
        print('Car %s ending charge at %s' % (car_id, env.now))
        print('Queue size: %s' % len(res_pool.queue))

def load_queue(env, res_pool):
    """
    create 200 charging processes.
    each one will queue up for a charing station
    """
    for i in range(1,201):
        env.process(charge_process(env, res_pool, i))

# boot
env = simpy.Environment()
res_pool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

load_queue(env, res_pool)

env.run(900)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael. Just a quick question: when I run your code the queue starts to reduce one by one. In fact, here is a part of the outcome: Car 1 starting to charge at 0 Car 1 ending charge at 90 Queue size: 199 Car 2 starting to charge at 90 Car 2 ending charge at 180 Queue size: 198 There are two problems:  The First problem is that  if we change the delay from 90 to 1 then once all cars in the queue are done then no new car is generated  (in fact there is no car 201, 202, ...)

Comment: The second problem is that the queue should not reduce at all. Why? Because the moment the first car in the queue (car 1) starts receiving service, Car 201 should in fact enters the queue. I do really appreciate it if you help me with these issues

Comment: two ways to change that.  one is to add a infinite while loop to charge_process so the car immediately queues back up for charging when if finishes charing.  Or add another process similar to  load_queue but as a infinite loop and has a time out in it to space out the arrivals to of new cars.